# Problem with getting attachments on apple mail

Tags: iphone, mail.app, macbook-pro, email

I occasionally have an issue that if I open up an email on my iphone or ipad that has an attachment, when I open it up on my macbook in mail the message will appear but without the attachment.  How can I fix this?  If I forward myself the message it will appear with the attachment but I'm getting tired of doing that.

Comment: what's the protocol you are using? POP or IMAP?  I am using POP on either iPad or MBP, without the problem you mentioned.

Comment: I also encountered this issue some time ago with attached pictures sometimes not displayed anymore. I'm using Google Apps mail servers with IMAP. These images still display correctly in the webmail app though. Nothing I can do to help but I'll definitely follow-up this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I had this behavior often when **View > Mail> As pure text** was selected.

Selecting **Best alternative** did show the attachments.